# could not connect to database postgres

Tags: postgresql

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I am trying to install dspace 6.3 on ubuntu server 18.04 but after installing postgresql when I run the command `createuser -U postgres -d -A -P dspace`    I am getting the above error help please

Comment: You started the pgsql daemon already?

Comment: Please confirm that the `postmaster` process started up and is still running (try `ps -ef | grep postmaster`).  Also, you may want to check your logs to see if postgres printed any errors

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the server? Try `sudo service postgresql restart` or `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`